# Different ways of paining cube with 3 colors

Tags: combinations, puzzle, counting

In how many different ways can a cube be painted by using three different colors of paint?

Comment: Unless you give more detail, I'm gonna say "uncountably infinitely many". You probably left out some restriction on how to pain (e.g. one color per side). But in any case, I don't see this being even remotely on-topic for a *programming* Q&A site.

Comment: Why do you want to *pain* the cube in the first place? What did it ever do to hurt you?

Comment: @delnan assume there are infinitely many ways of doing this (which is not correct, because the cube has a finite number of sides and we have a finite number of colours), why on earth would this set be uncountable?

Comment: @delnan I don't see what more detail you could possibly want, or how you come to the conclusion that it could possibly be infinitely many, let alone uncountably so.

Comment: @Radix You're making the assumption of one color per side (which I even mentioned myself!). But can't we put more colors on each side? Can't we paint a complicated picture on a side? A single side, modeled as plane in R², already has uncountably many points, I made the not-really-serious assumption that we can point any of these point differently.

Comment: @Kaz Details on how we can paint the cube and what counts as a different way of paining it. See above for more examples, and note that "uncountably infinitely many" was a joke.

Comment: That's a pretty natural assumption considering the question is posted on a programming QA website

Comment: @Radix We don't use assumptions in the programming. We use specifications

Answer (score 5):

It is a harder question than `3^6` if you interpret it in the only interesting way possible: how many distinct (i.e. up to symmetry) ways are there to color a cube.  Here's a paper: http://www.math.wayne.edu/~danf/talks/CF.pdf, and the answer is apparently 57.

Answer (score 0):

Why? The answer is as always: 42

(ps. 3^6=729)